# Grails, Integration Testing, mocking a bean method while testing a service with Spock

Tags: grails, integration-testing, spock

I'm having an issue performing an integration test in Grails 2.4.5.

The service I want to test looks like this:

```
class MyService {

    def myBean

    def serviceMethod() {
        myBean.beanMethod()
    }
}
```

where `myBean` is defined in `resources.groovy`:

```
beans = {
    myBean(MyBeanImpl)
}
```

And here comes the integration test:

```
MyServiceIntegrationSpec extends IntegrationSpec {

    def myService

    def setup() {
        def myBeanMock = Mock(MyBeanImpl)
        myBeanMock.beanMethod(_) >> 'foo'
        myService.myBean = myBeanMock
    }

    void "silly test"() {
        expect: 
        myService.serviceMethod() == 'foo'
    }
}
```

Well, this badly fails since `myService.serviceMethod()` returns `null`.

I've already tried

```
ReflectionTestUtils.setField(myService, 'myBean', myBeanMock)
```

instead of

```
myService.myBean = myBeanMock
```

with no luck.

Of course this simplified example could be handled with a unit test, but the real case I'm facing needs an integration test since data persistence is involved.

Comment: `myBeanMock.beanMethod(_) >> 'foo'` expects one parameter. You can either use `myBeanMock.beanMethod() >> 'foo'` or `myBeanMock.beanMethod(*_) >> 'foo'`. Either case mocking should not be part of Integration spec because this is an integration test. In your case as explained, there might be a need.

Comment: Oook, shame on me, I was really stuck on a trivial mistake! `myBeanMock.beanMethod(*_) >> 'foo'` worked for me, thanks a lot. I agree that integration testing shouldn't involve mocking, but `beanMethod()` performs a call to a SOAP service, and I don't want my test to depend upon something I can't control.

Comment: By the way, how can I accept your comment as the answer?

Comment: Added comment as answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`myBeanMock.beanMethod(_) >> 'foo'` expects one parameter.

You can either use

`myBeanMock.beanMethod() >> 'foo'`

or

`myBeanMock.beanMethod(*_) >> 'foo'`.

Either case mocking should not be part of Integration spec because this is an integration test. In your case as explained, there might be a need.